# Sub-Accordion jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following jQuery Accordion in which I also want to include a Sub-Accordion:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        animate: 500
    }).on("click", "div", function (e) {
        $("div.ui-accordion-header").each(function (i, el) {
            if ($(this).is(".ui-state-active")) {
                $(this).find(".panel-icon").html("-")
            } else {
                $(this).find(".panel-icon").html("+")
            }
        })
    });
});
```

**HMTL:**

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="js_button"><span class="panel-icon">+</span>Parent1</div>
    <div class="panel">

        <div class="accordion">
        <div class="js_button"><span class="panel-icon">+</span>Child1</div>
        <div class="panel">
        <p> Child1 Content </p>
        </div>

        <div class="accordion">
        <div class="js_button"><span class="panel-icon">+</span>Child2</div>
        <div class="panel">
        <p> Child2 Content </p>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="accordion">
    <div class="js_button"><span class="panel-icon">+</span>Parent2</div>
    <div class="panel">
    <p>Parent2 Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.accordion {
    float: left;
    line-height: 2.0;
    width: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
     margin-top: 1%;
}
.js_button {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline-width: 0;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.js_button:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: #000;
}
.panel {
    width: 99%;
    height: 20%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
}
span.panel-icon {
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
}
```

As you can see the first section of the HTML ("Parent1") contains of two child elements ("Child1" and "Child2"). The parent elements work perfectly but once I include the children with the exact same code as the parents the accordion is not working anymore.
How can I include the children correctly into my accordion or what do I have to do change in the code for the child elements?

Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: Here is also a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ypv8yow1/16/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your `div` s are not closed properly and accordion was also working but it wasn't just visible. Changing `height: 20%` of `panel` class to `height: 40%` will solve your problem.

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d0jj58rt/)

CSS:

```
.panel {
    width: 99%;
    height: 40%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="js_button"><span class="panel-icon">+</span>Parent1</div>
    <div class="panel">

        <div class="accordion">
          <div class="js_button"><span class="panel-icon">+</span>Child1</div>
            <div class="panel">
              <p> Child1 Content </p>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="accordion">
          <div class="js_button"><span class="panel-icon">+</span>Child2</div>
            <div class="panel">
              <p> Child2 Content </p>
            </div>
       </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="accordion">
    <div class="js_button"><span class="panel-icon">+</span>Parent2</div>
    <div class="panel">
    <p>Parent2 Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ahh, I didn't see the div. Thank you :-)